# Installation problems, Ubuntu 22.10 on Acer Aspire 3410 1tb, 4gb ram

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, acer

I know I'm late joining the party. I've reviewed many Acer related installation issues and I'm still confused.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.10-desktop-amd via usb drive to an Acer Aspire running windows 10.
The last point of failure was and attempted install resulting in "ubi-partman exit code 10".

Leading up to that point, I had to piece together information of other postings and don't fully understand the partition conclusion I've been trying.

The hard disk is a Raid.
I used the following partition settings, my first question is "Do these make sense"?
Followed by, "Do I need additional partition settings to get bast the "ubi partman error" ?

- /dev/sdg4 swap             4096mb
- /dev/sdg5 ext4      /boot  200mb
- /dev/sdg6 refi             103mb
- /dev/sdg7 biosgrub         1mb
- /dev/sdg8 ext4      /      7762mb

I haven't done anything with the first partition (sdg1 - 3)

The Ubuntu test seems stable, despite the fact that I am still on the learning path.
Hopefully someone might have some insight into so old a system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As older lighter weight system, you may be better off with lighter weight flavor. And better to use LTS version like 22.04 for long term support. Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours I like Kubuntu which is more mid-weight. Why is drive sdg, is this an external drive. Normally internal drive is sda? You do not need /boot unless using full drive encryption. What is refi? You mean ESP - efi system partition? You do not need both ESP for UEFI boot and bios_grub for BIOS boot. and if UEFI system and Windows in UEFI boot mode use UEFI.

Comment: Ok, I've stepped back and created a flash drive for 22.04, but I still have the same questions on partition allocation. 
Also note that I don't think the hard drive is showing up on the partition page.
I ran the sudo partition table command and it shows the partition table as: msdos

And on the ubuntu installation page the thumb drive (sdg) is showing up for partitioning and installation. This was probably my problem with v22.10.
Have you encountered this before?

Comment: I think I'm further along now, 
I found another posting that indicated I needed to run: sudo apt-get remove dmraid

Comment: Do you have Windows? If MBR(msdos), that would be BIOS, not newer UEFI. I prefer gpt whether UEFI or BIOS with Ubuntu, but Windows only works in BIOS mode with MBR and only with UEFI and gpt partitioning. If BIOS and gpt with Ubuntu, you need 1MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag. Are you installing from one flash drive to another?